# Python - Files - Changing line numbers based on search results

Tags: python, file, search, line-numbers

I need to search a debug file for a specific string or error and then, once it's found, look up the file by 6 lines and then print whatever that line 6 above has in it.

```
import linecache

file = "/file.txt"
fh = open("/file.txt", "r")
lookup = 'No Output'

with fh as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            numUp = num + 6
            new = linecache.getline(file, numUp)        
            print new
```

I tried adding doing something along the lines of "num += 6" whenever I find "The term I need to search" but my output is either blank or I receive this error:

```
File "testRead.py", line 12
    print new
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

If there's also another way to do "search, then scan up n-lines, then print/return" in a way that's line by line, that'd be great to know as well because the files I'll be working with vary greatly in size.

I upped an example file of some of the things I typically see: http://pastebin.com/mzvCfZid
Any time I hit the string "(Err: No Output)", I need to find its associated ID, which is the number 6 lines above the error. So "No Output is what I'd need to search for.

::Edit::

Comment: As it is presented here, the indentation is correct and the code runs.  Check your source file: you may have spaces and tabs mixed or some such subtle format problem.  The code generates no output however because line `num+6` is blank in `file.txt`.  I suspect that you may want line `num+5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the functionality of a `deque`:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>>
>>> lines = deque(maxlen = 7)
>>> for i in range(35):
...   lines.append(i)
...
>>> print lines
# Note your 6 lines earlier would be lines[0] here.
deque([28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34], maxlen=7)
```